# Rd created without export

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm documenting an internal, non-exported function. roxygen2 is creating an Rd file even though there is no `@export` tag in the documentation. roxygen2 created an Rd file for the following documentation. What am I missing?

```
    #' Check validity of a
    #' @param a A logical value
    arg_check_a = function(a) {
      if (!is.logical(a)) {
        stop("a must be a logical value")
      }
    }
```

Comment: `@export` is about whether the function is exported i.e. available to the user. It's not about whether the documentation is "exported". It's not uncommon for non-exported functions to have manual pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`@noRd`](https://style.tidyverse.org/documentation.html#internal-functions).

> Use the @noRd tag to prevent .Rd files from being generated.

I'm also a fan of marking them `#' @keywords internal`, which (according to the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html)):

> `@keywords internal` is useful because it removes the function from the documentation index; it’s useful for functions aimed primarily at other developers, not typical users of the package.

(Most of this is derived from https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/684)

Comment: Perhaps I can see some utility, and thank you for the meta link, @NelsonGon.